# Pull Notification in Android

Tags: android

I want to implement notification in my android app. 
The case is, I want to show the notifications when my app is closed and turn off when app is opened. So basically I want to show the notifications when the app is closed.

So what should I use in this situation? Should I use Service + AlarmManager?

Can anyone give me some example or reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NotificationManager for notifications, and for start/close you can use onCreate() and onDestroy(). [Activity lifetime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: ya but what should i use; BroadcastReceiver or Service.

Comment: Nothing. Android will make that for you. He know what to do when you call onDestroy(). Put there notification for "close application" and it will show when you leave out from application.